# find bugs intellij plugin does report when bug is cleaned up

Tags: intellij-idea, findbugs

I installed and ran find bugs on my Intellij project, then proceeded to clean up my code.   After I re-ran the analysis, and it reported the same bugs even though they were cleaned up.

Even after a re-install the same thing happened, it still seems to report fixed bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Findbugs runs on bytecode. Once you fix your code, you should make sure your code is recompiled. If you do that in intellij, try to perform "rebuild project" before running findbugs again.